# Fiware Context Brocker How to query entities with not equal condition to its ID

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

lets assume I have three Room entities with ids

urn:ngsi-Id:Room:Room1,
urn:ngsi-Id:Room:Room2,
urn:ngsi-Id:Room:Room3

Now I want to query all entities where id not equal urn:ngsi-Id:Room:Room2.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
GET /v2/entities/?q=id!=Room2
```

Comment: Hi @Jose, I tried this option, but no results are coming. Note: I changed the question with correct NGSI IDs

Comment: why don't you try an idPattern using a Regular Expression which matches all Room's ids excepting Room2 ?

Comment: Hi Jose, could you please give a sample. I tried and failed on this approach also. Not sure what is the exact syntax for doing that. Not able to see examples from Fiware docs also.

Comment: I think `q=id!=Room2` is not going to work, as `q` is for attributes. The solution based in idPattern seems better.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
GET /v2/entities?idPattern=Room[^2]
```

This is not perfect (for instance, it assumes your have from Room0 to Room9, but with two-digits suffixes it may not work as expected) but the exact regex lays out of the scope of this answer (which is about the Orion API).

There is a lot of literature about regex expression out there and debugging tools (as this one: https://rubular.com/)